# How do I access nested array within a cell in a parquet table using spark and python?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to pull the 'text' in the sentiment column in my table and filter it by city = london.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
name    city    sentiment
    harry   london  "[
                  Row(score='0.999926',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.640237'),
                  text='happy'),
                  Row(score='0.609836',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.607594'),
                  text='sad'),
                  Row(score='0.58564',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.6833'),
                  text='mad')
                ]"
sally   london  "[
                  Row(score='0.999926',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.640237'),
                  text='sad'),
                  Row(score='0.609836',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.607594'),
                  text='mad'),
                  Row(score='0.58564',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.6833'),
                  text='agitated')
                ]"
gary    london  "[
                  Row(score='0.999926',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.640237'),
                  text='excited'),
                  Row(score='0.609836',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.607594'),
                  text='down'),
                  Row(score='0.58564',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.6833'),
                  text='agitated')
                ]"
mary    manchester  "[
                  Row(score='0.999926',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.640237'),
                  text='sad'),
                  Row(score='0.609836',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.607594'),
                  text='low'),
                  Row(score='0.58564',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.6833'),
                  text='content')
                ]"
gerry   manchester  "[
                  Row(score='0.999926',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.640237'),
                  text='ecstatic'),
                  Row(score='0.609836',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.607594'),
                  text='good'),
                  Row(score='0.58564',
                  sentiment=Row(score='-0.6833'),
                  text='bad')
                ]"
```

My code currently looks like this but it doesn't work:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

data= spark.read.parquet("INSERT S3 TABLE").where("city LIKE 'london' AND sentiment['text=']")
df = sharethis.toPandas()
print (df)
```

And I want the output to look like this:

```
name    city    sentiment
harry   london  happy
harry   london  sad
harry   london  mad
sally   london  sad
sally   london  mad
sally   london  agitated
gary    london  sad
gary    london  low
gary    london  content
```

Does anyone know how I can go about accessing the array in the sentiment column in order to pull the text?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to do it with pyspark? Looks like a generic python map function would work.

Comment: Yes I want all the calculations to occur within pyspark as it's faster then pulling data, then pulling a filtered sample from that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first create a dataframe with the data of your example:

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('explode_example').getOrCreate()

data = [
    ("harry", "london", [
        {"score": "0.999926", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.640237"}, "text": "happy"},
        {"score": "0.609836", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.607594"}, "text": "sad"},
        {"score": "0.58564", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.6833"}, "text": "mad"}
    ]),
    ("sally", "london", [
        {"score": "0.999926", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.640237"}, "text": "sad"},
        {"score": "0.609836", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.607594"}, "text": "mad"},
        {"score": "0.58564", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.6833"}, "text": "agitated"}
    ]),
    ("gary", "london", [
        {"score": "0.999926", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.640237"}, "text": "excited"},
        {"score": "0.609836", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.607594"}, "text": "down"},
        {"score": "0.58564", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.6833"}, "text": "agitated"}
    ]),
    ("mary", "manchester", [
        {"score": "0.999926", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.640237"}, "text": "sad"},
        {"score": "0.609836", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.607594"}, "text": "low"},
        {"score": "0.58564", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.6833"}, "text": "content"}
    ]),
    ("gerry", "manchester", [
        {"score": "0.999926", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.640237"}, "text": "ecstatic"},
        {"score": "0.609836", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.607594"}, "text": "good"},
        {"score": "0.58564", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.6833"}, "text": "bad"}
    ])
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = ["name", "city", "sentiment"])
```

What you have is the following dataframe:

```
df.show(truncate=False)

+-----+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name |city      |sentiment                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-----+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|harry|london    |[[sentiment -> {score=-0.640237}, score -> 0.999926, text -> happy], [sentiment -> {score=-0.607594}, score -> 0.609836, text -> sad], [sentiment -> {score=-0.6833}, score -> 0.58564, text -> mad]]        |
|sally|london    |[[sentiment -> {score=-0.640237}, score -> 0.999926, text -> sad], [sentiment -> {score=-0.607594}, score -> 0.609836, text -> mad], [sentiment -> {score=-0.6833}, score -> 0.58564, text -> agitated]]     |
|gary |london    |[[sentiment -> {score=-0.640237}, score -> 0.999926, text -> excited], [sentiment -> {score=-0.607594}, score -> 0.609836, text -> down], [sentiment -> {score=-0.6833}, score -> 0.58564, text -> agitated]]|
|mary |manchester|[[sentiment -> {score=-0.640237}, score -> 0.999926, text -> sad], [sentiment -> {score=-0.607594}, score -> 0.609836, text -> low], [sentiment -> {score=-0.6833}, score -> 0.58564, text -> content]]      |
|gerry|manchester|[[sentiment -> {score=-0.640237}, score -> 0.999926, text -> ecstatic], [sentiment -> {score=-0.607594}, score -> 0.609836, text -> good], [sentiment -> {score=-0.6833}, score -> 0.58564, text -> bad]]    |
+-----+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Once we have the dataframe you need to **explode** the `sentiment` column:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

df_exp = df.select(df["name"], df["city"], explode(df["sentiment"]))
```

And the result:

```
df_exp.show(truncate=False)

+-----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name |city      |col                                                                  |
+-----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|harry|london    |[sentiment -> {score=-0.640237}, score -> 0.999926, text -> happy]   |
|harry|london    |[sentiment -> {score=-0.607594}, score -> 0.609836, text -> sad]     |
|harry|london    |[sentiment -> {score=-0.6833}, score -> 0.58564, text -> mad]        |
|sally|london    |[sentiment -> {score=-0.640237}, score -> 0.999926, text -> sad]     |
|sally|london    |[sentiment -> {score=-0.607594}, score -> 0.609836, text -> mad]     |
|sally|london    |[sentiment -> {score=-0.6833}, score -> 0.58564, text -> agitated]   |
|gary |london    |[sentiment -> {score=-0.640237}, score -> 0.999926, text -> excited] |
|gary |london    |[sentiment -> {score=-0.607594}, score -> 0.609836, text -> down]    |
|gary |london    |[sentiment -> {score=-0.6833}, score -> 0.58564, text -> agitated]   |
|mary |manchester|[sentiment -> {score=-0.640237}, score -> 0.999926, text -> sad]     |
|mary |manchester|[sentiment -> {score=-0.607594}, score -> 0.609836, text -> low]     |
|mary |manchester|[sentiment -> {score=-0.6833}, score -> 0.58564, text -> content]    |
|gerry|manchester|[sentiment -> {score=-0.640237}, score -> 0.999926, text -> ecstatic]|
|gerry|manchester|[sentiment -> {score=-0.607594}, score -> 0.609836, text -> good]    |
|gerry|manchester|[sentiment -> {score=-0.6833}, score -> 0.58564, text -> bad]        |
+-----+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Finally let's create a column with only the text, filter by the city and get the 3 wanted columns:

```py
# Extract text
df_exp = df_exp.withColumn("text", df_exp["col"].text)

# Select result columns and filter city
result = df_exp.select("name", "city", "text").where("city = 'london'")
```

And the result will be:

```
result.show(truncate=False)

+-----+------+--------+
|name |city  |text    |
+-----+------+--------+
|harry|london|happy   |
|harry|london|sad     |
|harry|london|mad     |
|sally|london|sad     |
|sally|london|mad     |
|sally|london|agitated|
|gary |london|excited |
|gary |london|down    |
|gary |london|agitated|
+-----+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test').getOrCreate()

data = [
    ("harry", "london", [
        {"score": "0.999926", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.640237"}, "text": "happy"},
        {"score": "0.609836", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.607594"}, "text": "sad"},
        {"score": "0.58564", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.6833"}, "text": "mad"}
    ]),
    ("sally", "london", [
        {"score": "0.999926", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.640237"}, "text": "sad"},
        {"score": "0.609836", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.607594"}, "text": "mad"},
        {"score": "0.58564", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.6833"}, "text": "agitated"}
    ]),
    ("gary", "london", [
        {"score": "0.999926", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.640237"}, "text": "excited"},
        {"score": "0.609836", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.607594"}, "text": "down"},
        {"score": "0.58564", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.6833"}, "text": "agitated"}
    ]),
    ("mary", "manchester", [
        {"score": "0.999926", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.640237"}, "text": "sad"},
        {"score": "0.609836", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.607594"}, "text": "low"},
        {"score": "0.58564", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.6833"}, "text": "content"}
    ]),
    ("gerry", "manchester", [
        {"score": "0.999926", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.640237"}, "text": "ecstatic"},
        {"score": "0.609836", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.607594"}, "text": "good"},
        {"score": "0.58564", "sentiment": {"score": "-0.6833"}, "text": "bad"}
    ])
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=["name", "city", "sentiment"])
df.show()

df.filter(df.city == "london").select("name", "city", F.explode("sentiment").alias("sentiment"))\
    .select("name", "city", F.col("sentiment.text").alias("sentiment")).show()

Output:
+-----+------+---------+
| name|  city|sentiment|
+-----+------+---------+
|harry|london|    happy|
|harry|london|      sad|
|harry|london|      mad|
|sally|london|      sad|
|sally|london|      mad|
|sally|london| agitated|
| gary|london|  excited|
| gary|london|     down|
| gary|london| agitated|
+-----+------+---------+
```